# \newenvironment: how to suppress leading space in environment content?

Tags: spacing, formatting, environments, white-space

I'm trying to define a new LaTeX environment that takes several arguments, the intention being to typeset the arguments in a fixed manner, followed by some ordinary paragraphs of text.

My problem is that the text content of the environment provided after the arguments are formatted with a leading space unless I put my text immediately after the final } of the final argument. I've provided a minimum working example of the problem below.

How do I modify my environment definition to suppress the unwanted leading space?

Thank you.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{example}[1]{
\par\noindent#1\par\noindent}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Leading space}

\begin{example}{Argument content}
Paragraph to typeset without leading space.
\end{example}

\section{No leading space}

\begin{example}{Argument content}Paragraph to typeset without leading space.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do not use `\noindent` that starts the paragraph too early. (latex almost never uses `\noindent` to suppress paragraph indentation

Comment: `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which certainly suppresses the initial leading space. The issue is that I'd like to typeset several paragraphs inside the new environment, so `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` unfortunately isn't the answer in this case.

Comment: that's why I asked:-) in that case you want `\@afterheading` or (probably better)  define your environment using newtheorem that define such headed environments and will take care of other things such as preventing a page break after the heading

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4019/no-indentation-at-the-beginning-of-environment/4034#4034